# CakePHP 3.0 URL Parameter

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-3.0

Previously, in CakePHP 2.0. I am able to access the tokenid inside the 'if it a post condition' after I hit the submit button.  Apparently now, after I hit the submit button in CakePHP 3.0, I am no longer able to receive the tokenid in the 'if it a post condition'. How can I continue to access the URL parameter inside the 'if it a post condition'? I know, it is really something simple. Can anyone enlighten me? What am I missing?

**URL**

/users/reset/15d3a535ecdd4ec705378b146ef572cf5bb9bfc2

**Controller**

```
public function reset($token=null) {

    if ($token) { //I am able to get the tokenid here. 

    Debugger::Dump($this->request->pass[0]); //I am able to get the tokenid here. 
    Debugger::Dump($this->request->params['pass'][0]); //I am able to get the tokenid here. 

         if ($this->request->is(['post'])) {
                 Debugger::Dump($token) //I am no longer able to get the tokenid.
                 Debugger::Dump($this->request->pass[0]); //I am no longer able to get the tokenid.
                 Debugger::Dump($this->request->params['pass'][0]); //I am no longer able to get the tokenid.
         }
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create(null, ['url' => ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'reset']]); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('password'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->button('Submit', ['type' => 'submit']); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end() ?>
```

**After Ofir feedback,**

I added the below inside the form.

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('resetToken', array('type'=> 'hidden','value'=>$this->request->pass[0])); ?>
```

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong but the token id is being passed by `GET`, and as far as I know - you can't pass data on the same request with `GET` and `POST`. Consider adding an hidden field to the form with the value of the token id.

Comment: Ofir, I've previously tried your method as well. But as soon as I hit the submit button. It doesn't receive $this->request->data['resetToken'] as it dependent on $this->request->pass[0] (URL Parameter). I can actually do what I've mentioned above in CakePHP 2.0 but not in CakePHP 3.0. So strange...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the for you created in the view template file is posting to another URL, you need to add the token to the form action url:

```
$this->Form->create(null, ['url' => ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'reset', $token]]);
```

If you are posting to the same URL, there is no need to specify the URL, as it will post to the same location:

```
$this->Form->create();
```

With that, you will be able to access the `$token` param in your controller after a POST.